# vcf-consensus script error: The sequence N not found in the fasta file

Tags: bioinformatics, variant, fasta, consensus, vcf-variant-call-format

I am trying to use this script ([vcf-consensus](http://vcftools.sourceforge.net/perl_module.html#vcf-consensus)) with a simple example but I have one error: The sequence "7" not found in the fasta file.

The syntaxis is:

```
Usage: cat ref.fa | vcf-consensus [OPTIONS] in.vcf.gz > out.fa
```

My FASTA file is:

```
TGGCTGGAACGGGACCTCACATTCTGTATTTGTCCCGATTGGCTAGCAACTTAGAACTTT
```

And my VCF file is:

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.1
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  SAMPLE
7   1   .   T   A   .   .   .   GT  0/1
7   2   .   G   A   .   .   .   GT  0/1
7   3   .   G   A   .   .   .   GT  0/1
7   4   .   C   A   .   .   .   GT  0/1
```

I compress by bgzip and index by tabix the VCF file:

```
bgzip vcfFile.vcf
tabix -p vcfFile.vcf.gz
```

And then, I execute:

```
cat fastaFile.fa | vcf-consensus vcfFile.vcf.gz > out.fa
```

I get this error:
    The sequence "7" not found in the fasta file.

Does anyone know?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us the result of `grep '^>' fastaFile.fa`

Comment: and your should ask http://www.biostars.org

Comment: @Pierre: the header is: ">gi|157696558|ref|NW_001838997.1| Homo sapiens chromosome 7 genomic scaffold, alternate assembly HuRef SCAF_1103279187418, whole genome shotgun sequence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your VCF only contain the chromosome '7' in column 1.

but your fasta header is

```
>gi|157696558|ref|NW_001838997.1| Homo sapiens chromosome 7 genomic scaffold, alternate assembly HuRef SCAF_1103279187418, whole genome shotgun sequence
```

tabix would work if your fasta header was just:

```
>7
```